# How can I get the headers from a redux-query response?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm sending a query request, and getting a response from the server just fine. The response header contains some information that I want to read. I can see there is responseHeaders in the error selectors, but I can't figure out how to get the headers for a success case.

Example taken from https://amplitude.github.io/redux-query/docs/connect-request

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { querySelectors } from 'redux-query';
import { connectRequest } from 'redux-query-react';

const getQueries = state => state.queries;

const getNotification = (state, notificationId) => {
  return (state.entities.notificationsById || {})[notificationId];
};

class NotificationView extends Component {
  // ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  isLoading: mapPropsToConfigs(props).some(queryConfig =>
    querySelectors.isPending(getQueries, queryConfig),
  ),
  notification: getNotification(state, props.notificationId),
});

const mapPropsToConfigs = props => [
  {
    url: `/api/notification/${props.notificationId}`,
    transform: responseBody => {
      const { notification } = responseBody.data;

      return {
        notificationsById: {
          [notification.id]: notification,
        },
      };
    },
    update: {
      notificationsById: (prevValue, newValue) => ({
        ...prevCharts,
        ...newValue,
      }),
    },
  },
];

const NotificationViewContainer = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  connectRequest(mapPropsToConfigs),
)(NotificationView);
```

In the above code, say that the call to /api/notification/${props.notificationId} returns a response with a header tag called "MyTag", like "MyTag: X123".

I want to be able to read that somewhere in the mapStateToProps. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Apparently the QuerySelectors has a function `headers` that isn't documented in https://amplitude.github.io/redux-query/docs/redux-selectors.